# Issues with CSS Grid and Media Queries

Tags: javascript, html, css

It seems like my media queries aren't working as intended with CSS grid currently and can't figure out why. I'm building a mobile-first way, so my first container is single columns. At about 850px I want to go to a 5 column view that contains two items but the media query is not working as intended.

index.html

```
<div class='container'>

    <div class='testbox'><h1>Test Box Walk Dog Hit Gym and Lift Bro Hit Gym and Lift Bro  Hit Gym and Lift Bro Hit Gym and Lift Bro Walk Dog Hit Gym and Lift Bro Hit Gym and Lift Bro  Hit Gym and Lift Bro Hit Gym and Lift Bro Walk Dog Hit Gym and Lift Bro Hit Gym and Lift Bro  Hit Gym and Lift Bro Hit Gym and Lift Bro</h1></div>




    <div id='main-grid'>

        <div class="container2">
            <h5 id='appHeader'>To-Do-List</h5>
            <div id='displayHideButton' >  <a href='#' id='addItemSymbol' onclick='hideInputAndChangeSymbol()' ><i id='symbol'  class="fas fa-minus-circle"  type='submit' ></i></a></div>
            <a href='#' id='addItem' ></a>
        </div>

        <ul id='list-body'>
            <li id='enterItem'><input type='text' placeholder="Enter List Item..."  id='newNote' class='inputEnterItem'></li>
            <li><span>Walk Dog Hit Gym and Lift Bro Hit Gym and Lift Bro  Hit Gym and Lift Bro Hit Gym and Lift Bro</span></li>
            <li><span>Hit Gym and Lift Bro</span></li> 
            <li><span>Stretch</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


</div>
```

index.css container code

```
.container{
display:grid;
grid-gap: 1.2em;
grid-template-columns: auto;
grid-template-rows: auto;
grid-template-areas: 
'option-panel' 
'todo-list';
margin: 2em;

}

@media only screen and (min-width:  850px) {
.container{
display:grid;
grid-gap: 1.2em;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
grid-template-rows: auto;
grid-template-areas: 'option-panel option-panel option-panel todo-list todo-list'
margin: 2em;

    }
}
.testbox{
    border:     1px solid red;
    background-color:   blue;
    grid-area: option-panel;
}
#main-grid{
 grid-area: todo-list;
 max-width:     30em;
 margin:    auto;
}
```

Comment: as pointed out by @ChrisSandvik in the answer below, its just a typo... so voting to close this question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forgot a semicolon after your grid-template-areas in your media query.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1.2em;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas: 'option-panel' 'todo-list';
  margin: 2em;
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 850px) {
  .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1.2em;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas: 'option-panel option-panel option-panel todo-list todo-list';
    margin: 2em;
  }
}

.testbox {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: blue;
  grid-area: option-panel;
}

#main-grid {
  grid-area: todo-list;
  max-width: 30em;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='testbox'>
    <h1>Test Box Walk Dog Hit Gym and Lift Bro Hit Gym and Lift Bro Hit Gym and Lift Bro Hit Gym and Lift Bro Walk Dog Hit Gym and Lift Bro Hit Gym and Lift Bro Hit Gym and Lift Bro Hit Gym and Lift Bro Walk Dog Hit Gym and Lift Bro Hit Gym and Lift Bro Hit
      Gym and Lift Bro Hit Gym and Lift Bro</h1>
  </div>

  <div id='main-grid'>
    <div class="container2">
      <h5 id='appHeader'>To-Do-List</h5>
      <div id='displayHideButton'> <a href='#' id='addItemSymbol' onclick='hideInputAndChangeSymbol()'><i id='symbol'  class="fas fa-minus-circle"  type='submit' ></i></a></div>
      <a href='#' id='addItem'></a>
    </div>

    <ul id='list-body'>
      <li id='enterItem'><input type='text' placeholder="Enter List Item..." id='newNote' class='inputEnterItem'></li>
      <li><span>Walk Dog Hit Gym and Lift Bro Hit Gym and Lift Bro  Hit Gym and Lift Bro Hit Gym and Lift Bro</span></li>
      <li><span>Hit Gym and Lift Bro</span></li>
      <li><span>Stretch</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```